# Some of the styles do not match with the config in tailwind 2 in production version

Tags: vuejs2, tailwind-css, production

This is the first time that I'm using tailwindCSS version 2 with postCSS version 7 in vue 2 project

this is my config file:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const tailwindCSS = require('tailwindcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const tailwindForms = require('@tailwindcss/forms');

module.exports = {
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/*/.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // Where I define styles
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    //
  },
  plugins: [tailwindCSS, autoprefixer, tailwindForms],
};
```

But my issue is some of the styles that I define in the config and then I used in the classes do not work properly in the production mode.

Does anyone have any idea why it is not working on production?

Answer (score 0):

In Tailwind CSS V3 purge has changed to content.

Quote from the Tailwind CSS V3 Announcement:

purge has changed to content
The JIT engine doesn't actually use PurgeCSS under-the-hood, so purge doesn't feel like the right name for these configuration options anymore.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

See this link for more info :
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6019

Comment: Thanks but I'm using version 2 of tailwind